# How to create AOM codec in gcc 12.2 and newer under Windows 64bit?

Tags: c++11

I want to produce codec without SIMD and assembler. I'm using basic functions `-std=gnu++11 -ftree-vectorize -g0 -O3 -DWINVER=0x0602 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0602 -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN=/"/" -DNOMINMAX`.

The problem is that when I create AOM codecs in GCC 11.3.X they work. On newer compilers GCC 12.2 and gcc13.0 no longer work. What have new features been added to these compilers?

Strange thing. Other libraries have no problem:
libjpeg-turbo, libpng, libtiff, dav1d, libgav1, avif, svt-av1, openhtj2k, openjph, openjpeg2000, ...

Comment: "No longer work" *how*? What's breaking? What code causes the breakage? Have you debugged your code?

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please learn how to create a [mre] of your code, and how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: In GCC 11.3 codec creates photos. GCC 12.2 and above go straight to DOS. At first I thought they were GCC bugs. Now I know that there are newer versions of GCC and the effect has been the same for year.

Comment: It's much more likely that you have a bug your code, than there's a bug in GCC. Have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: I tried to use produce debugging information '-g' instead of '-g0'. Without result. This isn't good idea because files .exe are very large.

Comment: If a "debug" build and a "release" build have different behavior, then it's a very important sign of *undefined behavior* in your code. Perhaps you're using uninitialized variables (most likely pointers)? Build and run with sanitizers (`-fsanitizer=address,undefined`) to catch many cases. And of course build with extra warnings enable (at least `-Wall -Wextra`) to see what the compiler can catch for you at build time.